# SQL query with aggregate and having a count greater than statement

Tags: sql, count, aggregate

My original query:

```
SELECT location, Item, SUM(TxQty) AS Total
FROM tblimInvTxHistory
WHERE TxDate > '2022-01-01' AND TxCode IN ('COSHIP', 'SHIP')
GROUP BY location, Item
ORDER BY 2
```

These are the results I get and they are verified correct:

| location | Item | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02 | 0103 06 10 | 10.00 |
| 02 | 0103 06 13 | 10.00 |
| 02 | 0105 08 14 | 4.00 |
| 01 | 0107-12-12 | 41.00 |
| 04 | 0107-12-12 | 7.00 |
| 02 | 0107-12-12 | 5.00 |
| 03 | 0107-12-12 | 4.00 |
| 05 | 0107-12-16 | 2.00 |
| 01 | 0107-12-16 | 14.00 |
| 04 | 0107-12-16 | 2.00 |
| 02 | 0107-12-8 | 1.00 |
| 04 | 0107-12-8 | 3.00 |
| 03 | 0107-12-8 | 1.00 |
| 01 | 0107-12-8 | 9.00 |
| 01 | 0107-16-12 | 4.00 |
| 04 | 0107-16-16 | 5.00 |
| 02 | 0107-16-16 | 4.00 |
| 05 | 0107-16-16 | 2.00 |
| 01 | 0107-16-16 | 31.00 |
| 03 | 0107-16-16 | 1.00 |

My question is can I use some sort of HAVING clause or something added to this query so that it will only output rows where the instances of location for a specific item are > 3 ?

I never could get anything to work without getting an SSMS error.

Ideally I would like this output where the like items have number of location instances totaling more than 3.

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utlwV.jpg)

Error Message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjwKM.jpg)

Comment: Do you simply want `HAVING COUNT(*) > 3`? (Between GROUP BY and ORDER BY.)

Comment: What was the error? Also, tag your DBMS to help filter. Lastly, what is the expected output based on your sample data? You may need to modify your sample to better display what you mean by `instances of location for a specific item are > 3`

Comment: Can you please post expected output. `instances of location for a specific item are > 3` does not make it clear to me what your filtering criteria is

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the output. This `SELECT` below will solve your problem. You did not specify which database engine you are using but most of them support *Common Table Expressions*; if this is not your case you can use subqueries instead, or  you can just let me know and I will give you the subquery alternative

```
WITH totals AS (
  SELECT location, Item, SUM(TxQty) as Total
    FROM tblimInvTxHistory
   WHERE TxDate > '2022-01-01' and TxCode in ('COSHIP','SHIP')
   GROUP BY location, Item
),
frequent_items AS (
  SELECT Item, count(*) AS counter
    FROM totals
    GROUP BY Item
   HAVING count(*) > 3)
SELECT location, totals.Item, Total
 FROM totals
 JOIN frequent_items
   ON totals.Item = frequent_items.Item
 ORDER BY totals.Item
```

So what the above `SELECT` does:

1. In memory builds a temporary table called `totals` storing the sum of quantities grouped by location and item as per your original query
2. From the above selected it builds another temporary table keeping only the items who appear more than three times
3. Joins the two temporary tables to give you what you want. `WHERE EXISTS` can be used as well for filtering

If this is not what you want as I said in my comment please provide expected result or clarify

Comment: Sorry, I'm using SSMS.

Comment: It does not matter what you use. The idea is the same. And if the syntax provided is not available you can use subqueries. My answer shows with no doubt how using `STANDARD SQL` you can achieve what you want. I added more explanation explaining how the solution works to my answer.

Comment: If you use SSMS that means most likely you are accessing an SQL Server database where the solution I posted will just work exactly as it is.

Comment: When I copy and paste you answer I'm getting the syntax errors below.

Invalid column name 'counter'.
Ambiguous column name 'Item'.

Comment: That was because I never run it myself being intended to give you an idea about the solution. I fixed it. See my updated answer. You just need to specify one of the temp tables in front of the `Item` in `ORDER BY` part

Comment: I truly am trying to follow your query instructions but I'm very much a novice at this and am just trying to work my way through it.  Based on your last comment about a temp table needing to be specified it appears that it is.  "ORDER BY totals.Item"  Is that what you're referring to?  See the error message picture added to the original post.

Comment: OK I had to recreate the table and run the SQL myself. The one in the solution works now.